# What do these countries have in common?

Tags: pattern, geography

The following alphabetical list contains independent countries with a certain common property. (The list is complete to the best of my knowledge).

> Australia, ???, Chile, Costa Rica, Cuba, ???, ???, Iceland, Laos, Liberia,
>   Luxembourg, Nepal, Netherlands, ???, ???, ???, Panama, Russia, ???, Slovakia,
>   ???, Thailand, ???, ???

Which countries have been replaced by questionmarks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> All of these countries have red, white, and blue flags.

Here's the list of question marks (in order):

> Cambodia, Czech Republic, France, New Zealand, North Korea, Norway, Samoa, Taiwan, United Kingdom, United States

Here's what I think your source was:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flags_by_color_combination#Blue.2C_red_and_white, and in this case it seems like Costa Rica may not count.